# python loop of files (.idf that are text files) and append one .txt file to each

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to append a .txt file on a list of .idf files (also text files). I have tried with os and glob but didn't get far. Any help appreciated.

I want the files to keep the same name, overwrite them.

```
import os

path = r"path"
appenddata = "append.txt"

filenames = list(os.walk(path))[0][2]
filenames.sort(key=len)
fileNums = len(filenames)

fileExt ='.idf'

for fileName in filenames:
    if fileName.endswith(fileExt):
        fileFullPath = os.path.join(path, fileName)
        with open(fileFullPath, 'append.txt') as f:
            f.write(appenddata)
```

I get a value error for append.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you are trying to do this:

```py
import os

path = r"path"
appenddata_file = "append.txt"

filenames = list(os.walk(path))[0][2]
filenames.sort(key=len)
fileNums = len(filenames)

fileExt = '.idf'

for fileName in filenames:
    if fileName.endswith(fileExt):
        fileFullPath = os.path.join(path, fileName)
        # Open the file in 'w' mode to overwrite its content
        with open(fileFullPath, 'w') as f:  
            with open(appenddata_file, 'r') as append_file:
                append_data = append_file.read()
                f.write(append_data)
```

Comment: Hi Ajeet, that works thank! I only modified to 'a+' as I wanted to append rather than overwrite.

Comment: Good to know that :)